# I cannot select a column to add a Referenced column in MySQL workbench when creating a Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a foreign key in MySQL Workbench and when I try and add a Reference Column it doesn't tick the box beside the column. This is happening for the second Foreign Key that I'm creating in this table. I was able to create one before but the second one doesn't seem to work. Here is what the first FK looks like:
[image: first Foreign Key]

The second one looks like this:

[image: Photo of problem]

As you can see there is no tick in the box and when I select the reference column it will reset. Is this a bug or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I realised that the data types were not the same. In the table that i was creating the FK the data type was `int(11)` however in the referencing table it was `tinyint(4)`.